# C - append argv[1] to end of unix PATH

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to write a C program that parses the UNIX "PATH" variable, and checks if the command line argument file (argv[1]) exists at any address on that path. The only thing that seems to not work is when I try to append '/' to temp, and then append argv[1] to that. In the while loop, temp becomes the next sub-path of the PATH variable, and then it checks to see if the filename entered in the command line exists on that path. What would be the best way to append '/' to the end of temp, and then argv[1] to the end of that?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

 void append(char* s, char c)
   {
        int len = strlen(s);
        s[len] = c;
        s[len+1] = '\0';
  }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    const char* path = getenv("PATH");
    char* temp;
    FILE *file;
    char sym = '/';

    temp = strdup(path);
    temp = strtok(temp,":");

    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%s\n",temp);
        //add "/argv[1]" to temp
        append(sym,temp);
        strcat(argv[1],temp);
        printf("%s",temp);
        file = fopen(temp,"r");
        if(file == NULL){
         printf("ERROR: File \"%s\" does not exist.",temp);
        }
        else{
           printf("Success! File \"%s\" exists.",temp);
        } 
        temp = strtok(NULL,":");
    }

    printf("%s",temp);




     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here `append(argv[1],sym);` you assume  `argv[1]` provides any addtional, free space do store any more characters to append. This surely isn't the case. Same here `strcat(argv[1],temp);`.

Comment: After you use `strdup`, you must free the allocated memory with `free`

Comment: I edited the code (see above) so that i didn't append anything to argv[1] and tested it, but it still did not successfully and argv[1] to the end of temp.

Comment: @szpal, i added that to the end, but my main problem is still appending argv[1] to temp

Comment: Now with `temp = strtok(temp,":");` you have the same issues as previously you had with `argv[]`. C simply does not allocated space for you. The above `strcat()` writes out of `temp`'s bounds.

Comment: Your code misses to `fclose()` the files `fopen()`ed successfully.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a working version without 'append' function:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    char* path = getenv("PATH");
    char* temp;
    FILE *file;
    char tmp_file[100];

    temp = strtok(path,":");

    while ( temp != NULL ) {
        printf("temp: %s\n", temp);

        sprintf( tmp_file, "%s/%s", temp, argv[1] );
        printf("tmp_file: %s\n", tmp_file);

        file = fopen(tmp_file,"r");
        if ( file == NULL ) {
          printf("ERROR: File \"%s\" does not exist.\n", tmp_file);
        }
        else{
          printf("SUCCESS! File \"%s\" exists.\n", tmp_file);
        }
        temp = strtok(NULL,":");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(You could use `asprintf` also rather `sprintf`, but then dont forget free the allocated memory)

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. I didn't know about "sprintf".

Comment: This approach will fail if the path in question added to what is being passed as argv is longer then 99 chars.

Comment: @alk, Thanks :D, but read my last comment before downvote...  I hope you have a good day

Comment: I simply do not consider your code a "*working version*". Also your "*last comment*" does not point out the possible pitfalls with your approach.

Comment: Also `asprintf()` is non-standard.

Comment: It is not wrong to use it, But it might be worth mentioning that it not necessarily needs to be available on the OP's platform, as it's non-standard C. And about C the question is.

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify temp because you interfere with the strtok.
The main problem of your code is managing storage for the file name char string. If you want to build a new string that is the concatenation of the path, '/', and argv[1], you need a storage for it. The simplest solution is to use an array for this. Make it long enough.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* path = strdup(getenv("PATH")); // <-- copy the path string
    char* temp;
    FILE *file;
    char fileName[1024]; // <-- Storage for the file name

    temp = strtok(path,":");
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("temp: %s\n", temp);

        sprintf(fileName, "%s/%s", temp, argv[1]);
        printf("fileName: %s\n", tmp_file);

        file = fopen(fileName,"r");
        if ( file == NULL )
            printf("ERROR: File \"%s\" does not exist.\n", fileName);
        else
            printf("SUCCESS! File \"%s\" exists.\n", fileName);

        temp = strtok(NULL,":");
    }
    free(path); // <-- delete the modified copy of path
    return 0;
}
```

We need to make a copy of the path string because strtok modifies it. It replace the ':' by a '\0'. That is the reason for the strdup.

fileName is defined as a big array of char that can contain the concatenation of temp / and argv[1]. To be perfectly correct we should check that strlen(temp)+1+strlen(argv[1]) is < 1024 to make sure we don't have a buffer overflow.

The sprintf is a formated print into a buffer that will do the string concatenation for us. The first argument is the buffer, the second the format, and the rest the arguments. The format is two strings separated by the / character.